# More efficient way to group by and count values Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A more efficient way to do this?

I have a sales records imported from a spreadsheet. I start by importing that list to a dataframe. I then need to get the average orders per customer by month and year.

The spreadsheet does not contain counts, just order and customer ID.

So I have to count each ID then get drop duplicates and then reset index.

Final dataframe is exported back into a spreadsheet and SQL database.

The code below works, and I get the desired output, but it seems it should be more efficient? I am new to pandas and Python so I'm sure I could do this better.

```
df_customers = df.filter(
    ['Month', 'Year', 'Order_Date', 'Customer_ID', 'Customer_Name', 'Patient_ID', 'Order_ID'], axis=1)
df_order_count = df.filter(
    ['Month', 'Year'], axis=1)

df_order_count['Order_cnt'] = df_customers.groupby(['Month', 'Year'])['Order_ID'].transform('nunique')
df_order_count['Customer_cnt'] = df_customers.groupby(['Month', 'Year'])['Customer_ID'].transform('nunique')
df_order_count['Avg'] = (df_order_count['Order_cnt'] / df_order_count['Customer_cnt']).astype(float).round(decimals=2)
df_order_count = df_order_count.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: please follow the guidelines here in posting a reproducible example for the contributors to help   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
g = df.groupby(['Month', 'Year'])
df_order_count['Avg'] = g['Order_ID'].transform('nunique')/g['Customer_ID'].transform('nunique')
```

Comment: I still had duplicates but still much cleaner.  Thanks!